# Creating an inverse of polygons

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-sp, r-maptools

I have downloaded [shapefile containing polygons](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/grump-v1-urban-extents/data-download) for urban areas. However, I am interested in polygons representing rural areas. Therefore I would like to convert the shapefile containing urban areas polygons to rural areas using R. Thus an inverse of it. My assumption is that areas can either be rural or urban.

Comment: have you found any solution?